# Click button in Htmlunit

Tags: java, javascript, html, htmlunit

I am writing a program in Htmunit where I need to fill in two fields with text, but to get to these fields I need to click on a button to allow for the fields to appear on the screen. I cannot create a new button and click it because that will return a new "page" which I do not want. What other way is there to click on a button without creating a new page, but rather stay on the same page. For reference, I am using this [website](http://cpdocket.cp.cuyahogacounty.us/Search.aspx). The page I need to do this on is the page after the terms acceptance page. I need to click on "foreclosure search", then enter information to the fields.